# Jquery event binding to select focusin/out

Tags: css, focus, jquery

I have this issue with jquery events binding for a `select` element. When I click on the select, the `.focus` class is supposed to be added. But selecting an option from the dropdown breaks the logic.

==> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FHWYr/)

Steps:

1. click on select
2. select an option
3. click on select --> `.focus` not added

CODE:

```
<a>
   <select>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
   </select>
</a>​

$('select').focusin(function(){
    $(this).parent('a').addClass('focus');
});
$('select').bind('focusout change',function(){
    $(this).parent('a').removeClass('focus');
});​
```

Comment: Is your jQuery code wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you're only adding the class when the select is focused, and then removing it when the select value changes.  The reason why the class never gets added back is because the select never loses focus when you choose one of its options.  Something like this should get you the behavior you're after:

```
$('select').click(function(){
   $(this).parent('a').toggleClass('focus'); 
});

$('select').blur(function() {
   $(this).parent('a').removeClass('focus'); 
});
```

**Edit** - I'm guessing that you want to keep the functionality of removing the class when an option is selected, which is why I'd bind to click instead of focus and blur.

Answer (score 0):

That is because selecting the option removes the focus from the `select` element just as you select an option from the `select`

So a `focusout` on the select is happening here .. So this obviously removes the class on the parent element of the `select`..

Also the class is not added because the `select` here is already focused..

So instead use  **.blur()**  and **.focus()**  events..

[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FHWYr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this, but I could be wrong:

```
$('select').on("focus", function(){
    $(this).parent('a').addClass('focus');
});
$('select').on('blur',function(){
    $(this).parent('a').removeClass('focus');
});​
```

Use `on` to bind events and use the `focus` and `blur` events for your select box. If I understood the question correctly this should take care of your issue.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FHWYr/)**